# Zyxel switch & SFP compatibility

Tags: sfp

I need to replace some ethernet cables with optical fiber (to limit damage from thunder strikes etc.), and I've got some Zyxel switches in both ends with SFP ports I want to fill with SFP-modules for optical fiber. In this particular case it's a Zyxel GS1910-24 in either end. The range is quite short, but different buildings; approximately 20 meters.

However, I can't find any information on whether Zyxel enforces only "Zyxel-made" SFP:s or not. I've found out what applies to a couple of other manufacturers, but nothing about Zyxel. To be specific: I've found no information that says that Zyxel switches only approve Zyxel's SFPs, neither no information that says that Zyxel switches will approve every SFP, independent of manufacturer.

Is there anyone who knows anything about what SFPs Zyxel switches approve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used a variety of SFP modules (including Ciena, Finisar, Cisco, Fiberstore.com...) in a Zyxel MGS-3712F without any issues.

Comment: I just want to give some feedback: I bought some no-name SFPs for 3Com, and they work in my Zyxel Gs1910s.

Comment: I can also confirm that they work in a GS1900 I accidentally bought =)